# Bad date update under a Windows directory

Tags: windows, file, date, registry

I'm under Windows 7. I have created a directory, and I often put many temporary files, I remove them, recreate them, etc...

I need to sort it by last date modification. With Windows file explorer, I use "détail form" and sort it by date of modification.

But I had a bug, sometimes, I delete a file, and when I recreate it, the date of modification is not the current date, but an old one.

It means somewhere in the registry, Windows has kept the file date, and recognize it when I recreate it, and give me a wrong date. This is very anoying.

Do you know where I can clean up the directory (into the registry ?), so Windows will correctly put the dates after. ?
(I think it may be closed to the option in, for each directory, Windows keep the information to show large icons, details, lists, etc...)

Comment: Windows dont store file dates in the registry.

Comment: Yes, but in my case, there may be a date storage elsewhere, because erasing the file, then rereate it does change the date